# Put Condition in Thymeleaf, Depending on its Value Type

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I  am creating  a table where I want to put value. Usually they are plain value, but few of them need to be displayed with their decimal value

I am using `formatDecimal` to cut all decimal value

```
<td th:each="dayWorked:${metier.getUserDayWorked(users)}">

    [[${#numbers.formatDecimal(dayWorked,1,1)}]]

</td>
```

Is there any way to include condition in it to only remove null decimal bit, but let those have be displayed?

Comment: I think it's possible, but it's not clear what you want.  Can you provide some sample values and how you want each displayed?

Comment: i would want that when a value is "20.0" i display "20" and when i have a value that is "19.5" i display "19.5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use modulus operator and divide your `dayWorked` value by `1` and check whether the remainder equals zero:

```
<span th:text="${dayWorked} % 1 == 0 
                    ? ${#numbers.formatDecimal(dayWorked,1,0)}
                    : ${#numbers.formatDecimal(dayWorked,1,1)}"/>
```

Comment: so, your answer is correcte, you juste need to change the output of day worked if true as folow  `<td th:each="dayWorked:${metier.getUserDayWorked(users)}" th:text="${dayWorked} % 1 == 0
                    ? ${#numbers.formatDecimal(dayWorked,1,0)} : ${#numbers.formatDecimal(dayWorked,1,1)}"> </td>`